# Парсинг HTML регулярными выражениями

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Решил написать дампер Сториса (портал с рассказами)

На странице рассказа вот так:

```
<h1 id="story_title">{ИМЯРАССКАЗА}
        <span class="vote">
```

Код таков:

```
        storyid++;

        listBox1.Items.Add("Checking story: " + storyid + "..");

        currStoryHTML = getHTML("http://site/story/" + storyid);

        if (currStoryHTML == "404NOTFOUND") return;

        Match match = Regex.Match(currStoryHTML, @"(?<=<<h1 id=" + "\"" + "story_title" + "\"" + ">>)(.*)(?=<span class=" + "\"" + "vote" + "\"" + ">)");

        if (match.Success)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Story with ID: " + storyid + " have name: " + match);
        }
        else
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Story with ID: " + storyid + " do not have name OR invalid..");
            return;
        }
```

Не важно, существует ли рассказ.
Всегда math.Success = false
Поможете?

Comment: Одна из величайших заповедей программиста - *никогда* не парси HTML регулярками, если тебе дороги твои мозги. А вообще, почему у тебя `<<h1`, а не `<h1`?

Comment: HTML не парсится регулярными выражениями. Для разбора и извлечения данных используйте Html Agility Pack: https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: Спасибо всем. Вопрос решен.

Comment: [Классическая ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/276994) по теме (должен же её кто-то запостить?)

Comment: Предпросмотр назад.. Зачем? Поставь скобки и бери нужную группу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никогда!! не стоит парсить Html регулярными выражениями, для парсинга Html есть бибилотека [HtmlAgility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Вы повторили комментарий от 14-го апреля, собственно.

Comment: Там были комментарии а не ответы

Comment: Пожалуй. Но если вы даёте ответ, может, стоит привести и примерный код?